# Pass a 's' (star) parameter to a macro

Tags: macros, errors

I would like to pass e.g. a `s` or a `t` parameter when calling a new macro.
I know this can be done by using `\IfBooleanTF#1` etc. a couple of times, but I like to know whether it can be done without evaluating them.

My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\newsavebox\mysavebox

\NewDocumentCommand\onehand{st+m}{%
  \sbox{\mysavebox}{\hand {#1} {#2} {#3}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\hand{st+m}{%
   \IfBooleanTF#1{1}{}%
   \IfBooleanTF#2{2}{}%
   #3%
}
\begin{document}
\hand{X}\\\hand*{X}\\\hand+{X}\\\hand*+{X}\\[2em]
\onehand{X}\usebox{\mysavebox}\\
\onehand*{X}\usebox{\mysavebox}\\
\onehand+{X}\usebox{\mysavebox}\\
\onehand*+{X}\usebox{\mysavebox}
\end{document}
```

I tried also without the braces like `\hand#1#2{#3}`
But this yields

```
X
1 X
2X
12X
X
*X
+X
*+X
```

Comment: `#1` or `#2` is either `\BooleanFalse` or `\BooleanTrue`, but not the `*` or `+` any longer you might expect. You have spurious spaces there as well

Comment: And bad boxes .... Never use `\\ ` to break lines outside special contexts such as `tabular`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not generally a good idea to use `xparse` this way. Anyway, you have to pass `*` or `+` to `\hand`, not `#1` or `#2`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\onehand{st+m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF#1%
   {%
    \IfBooleanTF#2{\hand*+{#3}}{\hand*{#3}}%
   }%
   {%
    \IfBooleanTF#2{\hand+{#3}}{\hand{#3}}%
   }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\hand{st+m}{%
   \IfBooleanTF#1{1}{}%
   \IfBooleanTF#2{2}{}%
   #3%
}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\hand{X}\\\hand*{X}\\\hand+{X}\\\hand*+{X}

\bigskip

\noindent
\onehand{X}\\\onehand*{X}\\\onehand+{X}\\\onehand*+{X}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I stated it in my question: I knew the solution with some **\IfBooleanTF#N**. I was just curious if it could be done otherwise. Thank you for pointing out I was misusing xparse.

Comment: @Jack No, the `*` or `+` are gobbled and you cannot know what token made the macro to return `\BooleanTrue` or `\BooleanFalse`.

Answer (score 2):

The `#1` and `#2` are evaluated by `xparse`'s parser to be `\BooleanFalse` or `\BooleanTrue` and are not recognized any longer as `*` or `+`, so `\hand` sees `{\BooleanTrue}{\BooleanFalse}{X}` etc., which are transferred in to `expl3` bool constants, i.e. displaying in Greek characters later on.

The easiest way is to use `moving arguments`, i.e. specify `\onehand` without arguments and let `\hand` do the evaluation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\onehand{}{%
  \hand%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\hand{st+m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{1}{}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{2}{}%
  #3
}
\begin{document}
\hand{X}

\hand*{X}

\hand+{X}

\hand*+{X}\\[2em]

\onehand{X}

\onehand*{X}

\onehand+{X}

\onehand*+{X}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note: One could check for  `\BooleanFalse` etc. and generate a token, but what would we get then, it's effectively the same like asking with `\IfBooleanTF`.

Comment: My MWE was too minimal! I need to put the stuff into a savebox and then your solution doesn't work anymore. I edited my question to reflect this (and removed spurious spaces)

Comment: @Jack: Yes, but in this case you're changing the question... It's your responsibility of providing the correct MWE and providing a clear question