# The use of \\ outside special circumstances

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

Several times I have seen this advice (or words to this effect): "Never use `\\` to break lines outside special contexts such as tabular." (for example, [Pass a 's' (star) parameter to a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384323/pass-a-s-star-parameter-to-a-macro)). I cannot find a source for this advice.

Indeed, "The LaTeX Companion" (page 104) has this:

> "Other ways of typesetting paragraphs are flush right and centered, with the `flushright` and `center` environments, respectively. In these cases the line breaks are usually indicated with the `\\` command, whereas for ragged-right text (the `flushleft` environment discussed above) you can let LaTeX do the line breaking itself (if you are happy with the resulting quality)."

Moreover, instances of the use of `\\` to format paragraphs are legion. Why is this use of `\\` ill-advised?

Comment: But ` \\ ` doesn't create a new paragraph, it creates a newline.

Comment: I think that goes without saying, or at least ought to do.

Comment: Related: [When to use \par and when \\, or blank lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664/2693).

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-or-blank-lines https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/best-choice-between-using-or-leaving-space-after-each-paragraph-to-end-the-pa

Comment: The question asks about using it to format paragraphs, but in the comment above you say you know it doesn't create a new paragraph. If the question is about paragraphs, it is probably a duplicate of one of the questions linked above. If it is not about paragraphs, it needs to be clarified to say what it is about.

Comment: One of the interactions I didn't understand as a newbie was how the last fontsize active at the end of a paragraph defined the parameters for the whole paragraph, in spite of any \\ that would otherwise occur.  It was very non-intuitive.  `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parbox{3in}{\normalsize This\\
\Huge is a test\\
\normalsize of the emergency\\
\tiny broadcast system}\qquad
\parbox{3in}{\normalsize This\\
\Huge is a test\\
\normalsize of the emergency\\
\tiny broadcast system\normalsize}
\end{document}`

Comment: If you change the \\ to `\par` in my above MWE, you will see the first 3 lines of the two examples are spaced identically (only the last is affected).  My example is more about fontsizes than \\, but a lack of understanding on how \\ works can definitely lead to unexpected results.

Comment: it isn't that using `\\ ` to end a paragraph is ill-advised, it is just that it does not end a paragraph, so if you want to end a paragraph you need to do something else (leave a blank line normally)

Comment: flushright and center (and verse) *are* special contexts. They are environments which are often used when you want to manually break lines e.g. in a title to get a pleasing result. It is outside of such special context that you should avoid ` \\ ` as you almost want a paragraph break instead in such places.